# redux toolkit slice accessing variable problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I was implementing the slicing method in my code but got the problem. When I try to access the old-fashioned way using actions, reducers, store, and types it works. so here is my new store:

```
import navPannelReducer from './navpannelSlice';



export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        navPannel: navPannelReducer
    }
})
```

Here is Slice element:

```
export const navPannelSlice = createSlice({
    name: "navPannel",
    initialState: [{
        pathnames: [document.location.pathname]
    }],
    reducers: {
        changePathName: (state, action) => {
            return { ...state, pathnames: action.payload }
        },
    },
});

export const {
    changePathName
} = navPannelSlice.actions;

export default navPannelSlice.reducer;
```

Here I try to get the variable:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const pathnames =  useSelector(state => state.pathnames.pathnames[0]);
```

This is what I get if I log my state:

[CLICK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbZLK.png)

[CLICKAGAIN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtGkL.png)

Also, I use the function from the state which handles the onClick event:

```
onClick={() => { dispatch(changePathName(['/home'])) }}
```

The error I get when I start my app: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathnames')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `navPannel` in the reducer. So just update like this:

```
const pathnames =  useSelector(state => state.navPannel.pathnames[0]);
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Finally the thing I didn't understand was creating new object inside ``` configurestore() ``` function. So ``` const pathnames =  useSelector(state => state.navPannel[0].pathnames[0]);``` properly works.